# Google Cross-Account Protection (RISC) API. Callback endpoint registration returns 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: google-cloud-platform, secevents

I am trying to register an api callback endpoint in google [Cross-Account Protection](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc), but I keep getting a `500 Internal Server Error` response with the following body:

```json
{
  "error": {
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Internal error encountered.",
    "status": "INTERNAL"
  }
}
```

HTTP `POST` Request:

- URL: `https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update`
- Body:

```json
{
  "delivery": {
                "delivery_method": "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/delivery-method/push", 
                "url": MY_CALLBACK_URL
               }, 
  "events_requested": ["https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/sessions-revoked"]
}
```

The authorization token is generated using the [script](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/risc#auth_token) from the official documentation

I use the following curl request for testing:

```sh
curl -X POST https://risc.googleapis.com/v1beta/stream:update -H 'Authorization: Bearer `AUTH_TOKEN`' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"delivery": {"delivery_method": "https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/delivery-method/push", "url": `YOUR_CALLBACK`}, "events_requested":["https://schemas.openid.net/secevent/risc/event-type/sessions-revoked"]}'
```

Comment: You misspelled **event_reqquested**.

Comment: @JohnHanley  Thank you. Fixed it. But I keep getting a `500 Internal Server error`.